# Generating an external link in Sphinx

Tags: hyperlink, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'd like to link to some URL in my Sphinx docs:

```html
<a href="http://some.url">blah</a>
```

I have found something similar in the docs: http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/extlinks.html - but it is rather about replacing the custom syntax with the link, by convention. Instead, I just want to generate a link to external web resource.

Answer (score 69):

See the [reStructuredText documentation](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-references). It can be done either with a named reference:

```
Test hyperlink: SO_.
    
.. _SO: https://stackoverflow.com/
```

Or with:

```
Test hyperlink: `Stack Overflow home <SO>`_.
    
.. _SO: https://stackoverflow.com/
```

Or with an embedded URI:

```
Test hyperlink: `Stack Overflow home <https://stackoverflow.com/>`_.
```

Comment: How about multiple words in the link text?

Comment: @MichaelGoerz in the second example, it contains multiple words in the link text, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but for the case of the named reference, it took me quite a while to figure out that the correct syntax is "` Stack Overflow_ `" (without the spaces -- can't properly format this in a comment) and then " .. _Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com". It's not in the documentation.

Comment: I think the documentation does say that you can put the text in backquotes (with the underscore outside), i.e. \`Stack Overflow\`_, but it's shown in the "inline markup" section of the quick reference, not in the hyperlinking section (unless you check the specification itself).

Comment: @AntonArhipov, is it possible to append string to href like `/docs/Orders.html` instead of `docs/Orders.html`? I m very much new to python

Comment: Can we decorate the link text (eg: use verbatim) with [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59007450/420867)

Comment: be aware, without the 'http://' or 'https://' it was treating mine as internal links!

Comment: How to add many links with the first method? I try different ways with double dots before every URL definition or not, but PyCharm keeps ignoring it.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me get this to work with a "named" reference using the syntax `Stack Overflow home <SO>`. I even copied and pasted this exact code! It just constructs a relative path to the current docs file, with `SO` at the end. Has this syntax been removed in recent versions?

Comment: @shadowtalker I made it work. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

This has been very frustrating, but I tracked down a solution as of mid-2023.

```
Presently, the fashion something called `"work-stealing" <BL94_>`_.
```

and later...

```
.. _BL94: http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/papers/steal.pdf
```

Note the *two* underscores: once inside the angle brackets, and once after the closing grave-accent. (Back-quote, if you're younger than the internet.) This correctly links the text `"work-stealing"` to the PDF article.

Comment: This is almost good, but you should use two underscores rather than one. I expanded on it in my own answer (would've posted a comment but couldn't figure out the proper inline syntax).

Comment: Just had this exact problem and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

A modification of Ian's answer:

```
Presently, the fashion something called `"work-stealing" <BL94_>`__.
and later...

.. _BL94: http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/papers/steal.pdf
```

The difference is that you should use two underscores at the end, rather than one.

This is because according to the spec, these are exactly equivalent:

```
`blah <foo>`_     <- only one underscore!
```

```
`blah`_

.. blah: foo
```

So the example with one underscore will generate a target for "work-stealing" as well, which is likely not what is desired.

Using two underscores will create an anonymous reference instead, which won't result in a separate new target.

Answer (score 1):

To state the options for the original question:
How to get

> `<a href="http://some.url">blah</a>`

Simple named hyperlink:

```
How to get blah_.

.. _blah: http://some.url
```

Named hyperlink with special chars or multiple words:

```
`How to get blah`_.

.. _How to get blah: http://some.url
```

Anonymous hyperlink (you need one link target for every reference):

```
How to get blah__ or
`How to get blah`__.

__ http://some.url
__ http://some.url
```

Embedded href (named and anonymous):

```
`How to get blah <http://some.url>`_.
How to get `blah <http://some.url>`__.
```

Embedded alias: (can be named or anonymous)

```
`How to get blah <blah_>`__.

.. _blah: http://some.url
```