# Preformatted (verbatim) hyperlink in Sphinx-reST-RTD

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I am building documentation with Sphinx-RTD.

I want to have a link somewhere, and be styled as a verbatim or preformatted text.

For example, say I have this verbatim:

`ALTER TABLE`

Is there a way to link it somewhere, say a :ref:`...` or even just a standard hyperlink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not mistaken the ["Replacement Text" directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#replacement-text) can help.

> As reStructuredText doesn't support nested inline markup, the only way to create a reference with styled text is to use substitutions with the "replace" directive:
>
> ```
> I recommend you try |Python|_.
>
> .. |Python| replace:: Python, *the* best language around
> .. _Python: http://www.python.org/
> ```

So maybe something like this:

```
Click |altertable|_ to read details about |altertable|.

----

Blah blah blah

----

.. _altertable:

Here are the details about |altertable|: blah blah blah.

.. |altertable| replace:: ``ALTER TABLE``
```